# AVCaptureSession start running in background thread it flash a black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I am running AVCaptureSession for the QR scan in the background thread.
and it shows a flash black screen a bit when screen navigating.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
       self?.captureSession.startRunning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `stopRunning` on `viewWillDisappear`?